# Create a master-details form using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My case is:

I have a voucher, which has header (date, name, final value) and details which is created from items table.

Items table consist of (goods_id, quantity, price....), 
Goods_id is the PK of goods table which has the full information about my stock goods

So, how to create a master form(Voucher) contains Items, every Item related to goods table?

Comment: Post your models with associations between them.

Answer (score 1):

Remaining just as abstract as the question I would suggest to use a nested form with a partial as described in [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).